# HIVE Server 2 - Query

Tags: hive

I am trying to execute a large query with about 60 column select with aggregation function in java using Simba HS2 HiveJdbcDriver this query is fetching some rows however I encountered the below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500312) Error in fetching data rows: *org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=f35bc652-40e9-4024-bca6-e9c28627a83a]:36:35;
```

I searched online and I haven't found any answer

Answer (score 0):

Such Error might happen because of server error such as Heap Memory overflow